# Login Logout Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, logout

I am currently working with asp.net using c# language. Just wanna ask anyone here, how to make my login status works? I mean, when user login, I have put the loginstatus control on top of page. After user click logout, it supposedly bring user to login page back, but it didnt work at that way. And when i click login, it gives me an error. can someone tell me why and how to overcome it? or is there any ways to implement other login logout function? Comments will be appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you provide code snippets, any errors you are encountering, and what you already have tried to fix it? You haven't really put much to go on here...

Comment: You can use `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`. But you better figure out the current problem as it may continue bringing down your efforts

Comment: First of all are you using ASP.Net Membership for the user authentication. if saw you can use loginStatus control. and use its templates for logged in user and un authenticated user. and have any controls inside and use them according to the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a Button or LinkButton for LogOut. And in the Button Click Event, add the following code to get back to your Login Page.

```
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session mechanism for that. You've to use a button for logout and on clicking this button first you have to clear the session and then you've to redirect user to the home page.